# neo4j functionality & unit testing - resetting the database

Tags: unit-testing, neo4j

I've created an application in node.js and have Mocha tests to perform automated unit and functionality testing.

I'm now trying to test database functionality, and want the database to be reset between each test for consistency.

**Solution 1**

Before each test I was running:

```
MATCH (n) OPTIONAL MATCH (n)-[r]-() DELETE n,r
```

and then populating the database with cyphers queries obtained using the neo4j-shell dump command. However, the problem with this is that those cypher queries utilise the internal neo4j ids to create links between nodes and relationships, and because the delete query above doesn't reset the internal neo4j id counter to 0 it all goes wrong when you try to run it!

**Solution 2**

I then looked at physically shutting down the neo4j server, removing the database directory and then rebooting it and populating it. This works, but it takes around 15 seconds, which is useless when I've got 200+ unit tests to run!

**Solution 3**

I've also looked at transactions in order to be able to roll the database back once the test had completed, but it seems that all queries have to go through the transaction endpoint. I don't think this is feasible.

.

Are there any other ways of doing this? I think solution 1 shows the most promise, but it'd mean going through and changing all my exported cypher queries to avoid using the internal neo4j ids.

For example I'd have to change:

```
create (_113:`User` {`firstname`:"John", `lastname`:"Smith",  `uuid`:"f843c210-26e3-11e5-af31-297c662c0848"})
create (_114:`Instrument` {`name`:"Drums", `uuid`:"f84521a0-26e3-11e5-af31-297c662c0848"})
create _113-[:`PLAYS`]->_114
```

To:

```
create (_113:`User` {`firstname`:"John", `lastname`:"Smith",  `uuid`:"f843c210-26e3-11e5-af31-297c662c0848"})
create (_114:`Instrument` {`name`:"Drums", `uuid`:"f84521a0-26e3-11e5-af31-297c662c0848"})
MATCH (a:User),(b:Instrument) WHERE a.uuid = 'f843c210-26e3-11e5-af31-297c662c0848' AND b.uuid = 'f84521a0-26e3-11e5-af31-297c662c0848' CREATE UNIQUE (a)-[r:`PLAYS`]->(b) RETURN r
```

Which is a real pain with a large dataset..

Any thoughts?

Comment: I don't think the _113 are internal node ids but just identifiers. Did you try Graphgen for generating you a bunch of cypher queries you can use in datasets ? http://graphgen.neoxygen.io

Comment: Christophe is right, it's just internal identifiers. And you shouldn't check/use internal node-id's in your tests.

Comment: And if your queries don't go through the tx endpoint I **very much** recommend to change your code / the driver you use to do that.

Comment: There's another possible solution, some code that acts as a simple stand-alone test server, with pre-made hooks for quickly clearing the contents of the DB:  https://github.com/graphaware/neo4j-resttest

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by "it all goes wrong"? As others have mentioned, a node variable identifier (like "_113") is just a temporary identifier that only has meaning within a single Cypher query. Such identifiers have nothing to do with node IDs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As FrobberOfBits kindly suggested, have a look at [GraphAware RestTest](http://github.com/graphaware/neo4j-resttest) built precisely for your purpose.